# threaded communication with email on a spring project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, email

All,

I am working on a new java/spring project. I would like to write a communication module which enables communication on a specific entity of a project. For example, A customer fills an expense report, any communication related to that expense should append to the end of the expense report screen and an email should be sent to the responsible party. This is straightforward and doable.

The second part is when someone reply's to that email it should append to the trouble ticket. I would need help with this.

I would appreciate if you could suggest ways to implement this.

Thanks in advance!.
-Aanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Spring Integration mail adapter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html